# Resubmit event to rebus

Tags: c#, rebus

After handeling a message, I need to send a new message.  It's some command event pattern, where I just handled a command, and need to submit an event (to the same bus).

Is the bus context where the message came from available in the handler?  If not how would you suggest I find back the right bus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds to me that you are implementing what is usually referred to as request/reply? In that case it's easy, because then the handler can just do this:

```
public class SomeRequestHandler {
    readonly IBus bus;
    public SomeRequestHandler(IBus bus) {
        this.bus = bus;
    }

    public void Handle(SomeRequest request) {
        bus.Reply(new SomeReply(...));
    }
}
```

Sent messages are automatically furnished with a [`rebus-return-address` header](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/Shared/Headers.cs#L26) which the handler of a message will use as the destination when you `bus.Reply`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  However, I don't get what the "return address" is doing exactly.  Is there some explanation somewhere or can you explain what this exactly is?

Comment: Yes: [Return addresses](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Return-addresses) ;)

Answer (score 2):

I created a Handler using the code you posted. However, when this handler is triggered, I get the following exception. All other handlers without a reference to IBus work as expected.

```
2/07/2014 14:53:10:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Het doel van een aanroep heeft een uitzondering veroorzaakt. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Er is geen paramet
erloze constructor voor dit object opgegeven.
   bij System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, B
oolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   bij System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   bij System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   bij System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   bij System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   bij Rebus.SimpleHandlerActivator.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Register>b__0()
   bij Rebus.SimpleHandlerActivator.<GetHandlerInstancesFor>b__b[T](Func`1 f)
   bij System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   bij System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
   bij System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   bij System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   bij Rebus.SimpleHandlerActivator.GetHandlerInstancesFor[T]()
   bij Rebus.Configuration.BuiltinContainerAdapter.GetHandlerInstancesFor[T]()
   --- Einde van intern uitzonderingsstackpad ---
   bij System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   bij System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   bij System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bij System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   bij Rebus.Bus.Dispatcher.GetHandlerInstances(Type messageType)
   bij System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
   bij System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   bij System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   bij Rebus.Bus.Dispatcher.Dispatch[TMessage](TMessage message)
   bij Rebus.Bus.Worker.DispatchGeneric[T](T message)   bij Rebus.Bus.Worker.DoTry()
Rebus.Bus.RebusBus WARN (Rebus 1 worker 1): Message RoodFluweel.Messaging.Models.Commands.SendPrintAtHomeTickets is forwarded to error queue
```

Comment: You're using `BuiltInContainerAdapter`'s `SimpleHandlerActivator` that just [uses `Activator.CreateInstance`](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/SimpleHandlerActivator.cs#L22) to create the handler which fails when the handler has a dependency in the constructor.

Comment: For real-world usage you'd usually use a container adapter to forward the call to your favorite IoC container's resolver method, but if you want to continue using the built-in container adapter, you can register your handler like this: `adapter.Register(() => new SomeRequestHandler(adapter.Bus));`